# Integer Factor Congruence

Tags: modular-arithmetic, prime-factorization, congruence-relations

Given an integer $N$, with unknown prime factors $f_1$, $f_2$ ... $f_n$, and given unique integers $k_1$, $k_2$ ... $k_n$, with $\sqrt{N} \geq k_i>2$ for all $i$ such that
$$f_1 \equiv 1\pmod {k_1}$$
$$f_2 \equiv 1\pmod {k_2}$$
$$f_n \equiv 1\pmod {k_n}$$
Does knowing $k_1$, $k_2$ ... $k_n$ in any way help to find $f_1$, $f_2$ ... $f_n$?

Comment: I think more context might help.  If, say, $k_i=2$ for all $i$, this really doesn't tell us much (it just tells us that $N$ is odd which, presumably, we could already sort out).  If the $k_i$ are large, then I suppose it cuts down on the search considerably.

Comment: @lulu, I provided more context in the question. Assume $k_i>2$ for all $i$.

Comment: gcd unknown ? just thinking of possibilities.

Comment: Dirichlet's theorem on arithmetic progressions tells us that there are infinitely many primes that are 1 mod $k_i$ for each $i$, so we can't say what the $f_i$'s are.

Comment: @boink they are at least bound by N. and all but 1 less than $\sqrt{N}$

Comment: in fact since they are all guaranteed be odd, we can double any odd $k_i$ and only look there. if we know $n$ we could Also argue for density.

Answer (score 0):

lulu made the point that, any time $k_i$ are all constant, you don't get much in way of help.  Here are a few things that will:

- Noting that $k_i$ multiplied by the negative of it's multiplicative inverse mod any prime that isn't $f_i$, is out as a higher equivalent modulus, because it would add to 0 mod the tried prime.

This means the following:

- odd $k_i$ can't have odd multipliers.
- $k_i\equiv 1\pmod 3$  can't have a  multiplier $r\equiv 2\pmod 3$
- $k_i\equiv 2\pmod 3$ can't have a multiplier $r\equiv 1\pmod 3$
- $k_i\equiv 1\pmod 5$ can't have a multiplier $r\equiv 4\pmod 5$

This and possibly confining their range, may help a lot.